# LINQ suggestion C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question reg using LINQ aggregate or groupby using C#

I have an User IList like:

```
Name--dept--age--sex
n1--d1--22--M
n1--d2--22--M
n2--d4--23--F
n2--d2--23--F
n3--d5--21--F
```

Based on the above IList, I would like to generate another User IList in the following format.

```
Name--age--sex--concatdept
n1--22--M--d1,d2
n2--23--F--d4,d2
n3--21--F--d5
```

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: Is `Name` unique? or is `[Name,Age,Sex]` unique?

Answer (score 4):

```
from u in users
group u by new { u.Name, u.Age, u.Sex } into g
select new
{
   g.Key.Name,
   g.Key.Age,
   g.Key.Sex,
   string.Join(",", g.Select(u1 => u1.dept))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Korach. I'll try this & get back to you

Answer (score 2):

So you just want to group the department by name, age and sex? Sounds like you want:

```
var query = people.GroupBy(person => new { person.Age, person.Sex },
                           person => person.Department);

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (var department in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}", department);
    }
}
```

(Or whatever you want to do with the departments of course.)

Answer (score 0):

```
userList
    .GroupBy(u => u.Name)
    .Select(g=>new{group = g, first = g.First()})
    .Select(x=>
      new
      {
         x.first.Name,
         x.first.Age,
         x.first.Sex,
         concatdept = string.Join(",", x.group.Select(xx => xx.Dept))})
```

Comment: Spender, everything works. The question I have is, how do I get data from system.linq.enumerable+whereselectenumerableiterator. FOr the concatdept, while debugging, I see it as system.linq.enumerable+whereselectenumerableiterator.

Comment: enumerate the expression in a `foreach` (i.e. store expression in variable and loop over that variable), or to make a list, add `.ToList()` to the end of the expression.

Comment: foreach (var x in userListTmP)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Info: {0}{1}{2}{3}", x.Name, x.Age, x.ConcatenatedDepe, x.Sex));
                } How can I enumerate with in this?

Comment: Spender, I'm a litte confused now.

Comment: Spender, I basically want a list of all of those in the second IList format I mentioned in my question